# How can I keep string data with aggregation when resampling data?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I'd like to average my minute data to 10-min averages of those 10 timepoints, however, I have important data in columns.

This is the first thing I tried `df1.resample('10min', on='Date_Time').mean(d).dropna()`

I used dropna() to remove the added rows of 10-min data by the resample function. Using the dropna() globally however, results in this results in lots of missing data.

I have tried:

```
numerics = (df1.select_dtypes(include=['datetime','number']).resample('10min', on='Date_Time')).mean(d).dropna()

strings = df1.select_dtypes(include=['datetime','object']).resample("10min", on='Date_Time').first().dropna()

df_10m = numerics.join(strings)
```

this is the top 5 rows of the df

```
{'Date_Time': {0: Timestamp('2020-02-04 10:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2020-02-04 10:01:00'), 2: Timestamp('2020-02-04 10:02:00'), 3: Timestamp('2020-02-04 10:03:00'), 4: Timestamp('2020-02-04 10:04:00')}, 'Tg (ºC)': {0: 35.58856153846154, 1: 35.72681666666667, 2: 35.94865000000001, 3: 36.24185000000001, 4: 36.51074166666667}, 'Tg (C) HSRI': {0: 46.03922307692308, 1: 46.179199999999994, 2: 46.330241666666666, 3: 46.40623333333333, 4: 46.40038333333332}, 'Ta (C)': {0: 31.03922307692308, 1: 31.179199999999998, 2: 31.330241666666666, 3: 31.406233333333333, 4: 31.400383333333327}, 'RH (%)': {0: 35.54615384615385, 1: 35.074999999999996, 2: 35.083333333333336, 3: 35.208333333333336, 4: 35.25833333333333}, 'WS': {0: 2.3515384615384614, 1: 2.3275, 2: 2.454166666666666, 3: 2.3666666666666667, 4: 2.5333333333333328}, 'Tr (C)': {0: 86.03059100103826, 1: 85.92113760389992, 2: 87.10761095323471, 3: 86.41824958826783, 4: 87.81529421945606}, 'm': {0: 80, 1: 80, 2: 80, 3: 80, 4: 80}, 'Ht': {0: 1.8, 1: 1.8, 2: 1.8, 3: 1.8, 4: 1.8}, 'PB': {0: 101.9, 1: 101.9, 2: 101.9, 3: 101.9, 4: 101.9}, 'vcomb': {0: 2.651538461538461, 1: 2.6275, 2: 2.754166666666666, 3: 2.6666666666666665, 4: 2.8333333333333326}, 'vself': {0: 0.3, 1: 0.3, 2: 0.3, 3: 0.3, 4: 0.3}, 'VO2': {0: 14, 1: 14, 2: 14, 3: 14, 4: 14}, 'VO2.1': {0: 1.12, 1: 1.12, 2: 1.12, 3: 1.12, 4: 1.12}, 'RER': {0: 0.8, 1: 0.8, 2: 0.8, 3: 0.8, 4: 0.8}, 'Tcl': {0: 36, 1: 36, 2: 36, 3: 36, 4: 36}, 'Tsk': {0: 36, 1: 36, 2: 36, 3: 36, 4: 36}, 'ε': {0: 0.95, 1: 0.95, 2: 0.95, 3: 0.95, 4: 0.95}, 'Ar/AD': {0: 0.35, 1: 0.35, 2: 0.35, 3: 0.35, 4: 0.35}, 'Icl': {0: 1.03, 1: 1.03, 2: 1.03, 3: 1.03, 4: 1.03}, 'Re,cl': {0: 0.023, 1: 0.023, 2: 0.023, 3: 0.023, 4: 0.023}, 'AD': {0: 1.9917607971689137, 1: 1.9917607971689137, 2: 1.9917607971689137, 3: 1.9917607971689137, 4: 1.9917607971689137}, 'AD:m': {0: 248.9700996461142, 1: 248.9700996461142, 2: 248.9700996461142, 3: 248.9700996461142, 4: 248.9700996461142}, 'Ta': {0: 304.18922307692304, 1: 304.32919999999996, 2: 304.48024166666664, 3: 304.5562333333333, 4: 304.5503833333333}, 'Pa': {0: 1.600406759479592, 1: 1.5918245414256496, 2: 1.60593338043295, 3: 1.6186268793904253, 4: 1.6203871372827314}, 'Pa.1': {0: 12.00305069609694, 1: 11.938684060692372, 2: 12.044500353247125, 3: 12.139701595428189, 4: 12.152903529620486}, 'Psa': {0: 4.5023345321866906, 1: 4.538345093159372, 2: 4.577482319523848, 3: 4.5972834444225095, 4: 4.595756475394181}, 'PB.1': {0: 764.25, 1: 764.25, 2: 764.25, 3: 764.25, 4: 764.25}, 'Abs Humid': {0: 0.01141684979152761, 1: 0.011350403625066736, 2: 0.011445325373048706, 3: 0.011532912296143744, 4: 0.011545676119064242}, 'v': {0: 2.651538461538461, 1: 2.6275, 2: 2.754166666666666, 3: 2.6666666666666665, 4: 2.8333333333333326}, 'M (W)': {0: 376.959744, 1: 376.959744, 2: 376.959744, 3: 376.959744, 4: 376.959744}, 'M(w/m2)': {0: 189.25954589316655, 1: 189.25954589316655, 2: 189.25954589316655, 3: 189.25954589316655, 4: 189.25954589316655}, 'H (W)': {0: 376.959744, 1: 376.959744, 2: 376.959744, 3: 376.959744, 4: 376.959744}, 'H (W/m2)': {0: 189.25954589316655, 1: 189.25954589316655, 2: 189.25954589316655, 3: 189.25954589316655, 4: 189.25954589316655}, 'fcl': {0: 1.3193000000000001, 1: 1.3193000000000001, 2: 1.3193000000000001, 3: 1.3193000000000001, 4: 1.3193000000000001}, 'hc': {0: 10.429773835114272, 1: 10.372937644718489, 2: 10.670143570681152, 3: 10.465437098406353, 4: 10.853123250589423}, 'hr': {0: 2.8152285937257235, 1: 2.8138458658081724, 2: 2.8288587842794275, 3: 2.820129539046607, 4: 2.8378387547428283}, 'h': {0: 13.245002428839996, 1: 13.186783510526661, 2: 13.499002354960579, 3: 13.285566637452959, 4: 13.690962005332251}, 'to': {0: 42.727652144400366, 1: 42.86024221094555, 2: 43.01897961346187, 3: 43.083643584372176, 4: 43.09396778675954}, 'σ': {0: 5.67e-08, 1: 5.67e-08, 2: 5.67e-08, 3: 5.67e-08, 4: 5.67e-08}, 'Rcl': {0: 0.15965000000000001, 1: 0.15965000000000001, 2: 0.15965000000000001, 3: 0.15965000000000001, 4: 0.15965000000000001}, 'C + R (W)': {0: -61.7854635996826, 1: -62.92983381965766, 2: -64.78260666774776, 3: -65.10727499145821, 4: -65.71445913620975}, 'W/m2)': {0: -31.020523994399518, 1: -31.595076029765245, 2: -32.52529458348094, 3: -32.688300263767424, 4: -32.99314818808373}, 'Ps,sk': {0: 5.94114568997784, 1: 5.94114568997784, 2: 5.94114568997784, 3: 5.94114568997784, 4: 5.94114568997784}, 'he': {0: 172.09126827938547, 1: 171.15347113785506, 2: 176.057368916239, 3: 172.67971212370483, 4: 179.07653363472548}, 'LR': {0: 16.5, 1: 16.5, 2: 16.5, 3: 16.5, 4: 16.5}, 'λ': {0: 2427, 1: 2427, 2: 2427, 3: 2427, 4: 2427}, 'Ereq': {0: 409.36381964806634, 1: 410.5260936917001, 2: 412.55058725207795, 3: 412.99813912411855, 4: 413.6137153206719}, 'Emax': {0: 283.93655875039144, 1: 284.24761905934344, 2: 284.6055046911687, 3: 282.899686582697, 4: 284.41267301639743}, 'Ereq.1': {0: 205.5286057592536, 1: 206.1121467373097, 2: 207.12858082078773, 3: 207.353282437908, 4: 207.66234374558525}, 'Emax.1': {0: 142.55555142664647, 1: 142.71172495380603, 2: 142.89140799221803, 3: 142.03497075793953, 4: 142.79459331695918}, 'ωreq': {0: 1.4417439636856977, 1: 1.4442551710731937, 2: 1.4495523819883425, 3: 1.4598748556880825, 4: 1.4542731550391408}, 'H.S.I.': {0: 144.17439636856977, 1: 144.42551710731937, 2: 144.95523819883425, 3: 145.98748556880824, 4: 145.4273155039141}, 'r': {0: 0.5, 1: 0.5, 2: 0.5, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.5}, 'Sreq': {0: 411.0572115185072, 1: 412.2242934746194, 2: 414.25716164157546, 3: 414.706564875816, 4: 415.3246874911705}, 'Sreq.1': {0: 1214.4291312179967, 1: 1217.8771629914465, 2: 1223.8830771384264, 3: 1225.210795918275, 4: 1227.0369799377163}, 'Slimit': {0: 1214.4291312179967, 1: 1217.8771629914465, 2: 1223.8830771384264, 3: 1225.210795918275, 4: 1227.0369799377163}, 'Cres + Eres': {0: 29.381387951616322, 1: 29.36348412795755, 2: 29.19176341566985, 3: 29.06887986733963, 4: 29.060487815537876}, 'Cres + Eres.1': {0: 14.75146412831249, 1: 14.742475185622073, 2: 14.656259655859772, 3: 14.594563719025947, 4: 14.590350335665013}, 'Heat': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}, 'Sweat Rate': {0: 2.1442913121799667, 1: 2.1787716299144644, 2: 2.2388307713842637, 3: 2.2521079591827498, 4: 2.270369799377163}, 'Black Globe Temp': {0: 6.539223076923079, 1: 6.6791999999999945, 2: 6.830241666666666, 3: 6.906233333333333, 4: 6.900383333333323}, 'HSS Score': {0: 8.683514389103046, 1: 8.85797162991446, 2: 9.069072438050929, 3: 9.158341292516083, 4: 9.170753132710487}, 'Sunny Factor': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 4}, 'Td (C)': {0: 18.14845384615385, 1: 18.194199999999995, 2: 18.346908333333335, 3: 18.4479, 4: 18.452049999999993}, 'WBGT (C)': {0: 26.6959487578496, 1: 26.780697622069766, 2: 26.9482556650566, 3: 27.051211098622655, 4: 27.052240739589937}, 'e (hPa)': {0: 13.121397641817339, 1: 13.135092168116461, 2: 13.343533435258518, 3: 13.495869716597092, 4: 13.506929744503669}, 'Category': {0: 'High Risk', 1: 'High Risk', 2: 'High Risk', 3: 'High Risk', 4: 'High Risk'}, 'Stadium': {0: 'WACA', 1: 'WACA', 2: 'WACA', 3: 'WACA', 4: 'WACA'}, 'City': {0: 'Perth', 1: 'Perth', 2: 'Perth', 3: 'Perth', 4: 'Perth'}, 'State': {0: 'WA', 1: 'WA', 2: 'WA', 3: 'WA', 4: 'WA'}, 'BOM_station_id': {0: 9225, 1: 9225, 2: 9225, 3: 9225, 4: 9225}, 'BOM_station': {0: 'Perth Metro', 1: 'Perth Metro', 2: 'Perth Metro', 3: 'Perth Metro', 4: 'Perth Metro'}, 'BOM2_station_id': {0: 9021, 1: 9021, 2: 9021, 3: 9021, 4: 9021}, 'BOM2_station': {0: 'Perth Airport', 1: 'Perth Airport', 2: 'Perth Airport', 3: 'Perth Airport', 4: 'Perth Airport'}, 'Measurement_device': {0: 'EMU', 1: 'EMU', 2: 'EMU', 3: 'EMU', 4: 'EMU'}, 'Longitude': {0: 115.880637, 1: 115.880637, 2: 115.880637, 3: 115.880637, 4: 115.880637}, 'Latitude': {0: -31.959454, 1: -31.959454, 2: -31.959454, 3: -31.959454, 4: -31.959454}, 'Day': {0: 'Day 1', 1: 'Day 1', 2: 'Day 1', 3: 'Day 1', 4: 'Day 1'}, 'measurement_type': {0: 'EMU', 1: 'EMU', 2: 'EMU', 3: 'EMU', 4: 'EMU'}, 'WS_conv': {0: 2.3515384615384614, 1: 2.3275, 2: 2.454166666666666, 3: 2.3666666666666667, 4: 2.5333333333333328}, 'WS_unconverted': {0: 2.3515384615384614, 1: 2.3275, 2: 2.454166666666666, 3: 2.3666666666666667, 4: 2.5333333333333328}, 'Numeric_Category': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3}, 'venue_type': {0: 'Major', 1: 'Major', 2: 'Major', 3: 'Major', 4: 'Major'}, 'time': {0: datetime.time(10, 0), 1: datetime.time(10, 1), 2: datetime.time(10, 2), 3: datetime.time(10, 3), 4: datetime.time(10, 4)}}
```

However, this too seems to result in lost data.

Comment: If change `.dropna()` to `.dropna(how='all')` it working like need?

Comment: Are missing values in original DataFrame?

Comment: thanks, @jezrael, this still results in many missing rows. I receive 1000 rows from a 27,674 row df, which should result in around 2,767 rows of data. So missing around 1700 rows still. Missing values are in the original df, yes

Comment: So if remove `dropna` and check output problem is in some rows are missing values instead numbers/strings/times?

Comment: yes data still seems to be missing from the resampled df, without using dropna. Still waiting on that custom code to run. Will get back to you later

Answer (score 1):

You can use this alternative with custom aggregate function `mean` for numeric else first value if exist. Last remove only rows with all missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with `how='all'` parameter:

```
f = lambda x: x.mean() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else next(iter(x), None)
out = df1.resample('10min', on='Date_Time').agg(f).dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: running this now, it's taking some time... will update once it runs. Thanks